# RadioButtons selected or not

Tags: java, android

Hi everyone I am trying to write a program that checks if all the radiobuttons I have are not selected, and print "Sorry you must select a radio button before continuing". I have gotten that message to print out, but when I select a radio button after that message pops up, I still get the "Sorry you must continue..." message.

Here is what I've come up with:

```
   no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
                RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
                RadioButton r3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
                RadioButton r4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
                RadioButton r5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);

                if(!(r1.isChecked() || r2.isChecked()) || r3.isChecked() || r4.isChecked() || r5.isChecked())
                {
                    riskLevel = Question1Activity.countPoints;
                    if(riskLevel >= 6 && riskLevel <= 9)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Question7Activity.this, "High Risk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), HighRiskActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if(riskLevel >= 3 && riskLevel <= 5)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Question7Activity.this, "Moderate Risk" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    if(riskLevel >= 1 && riskLevel <= 2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Question7Activity.this, "Low Risk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    if(riskLevel == 0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Question7Activity.this, "No Risk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Question7Activity.this, "Well buddy nice try", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

I know it's something really simple, but I can't think of what could be the problem.

-Thanks!

Comment: If you are using a bunch of `RadioButton` out of which only one has to be selected I would suggest using `RadioGroup`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if((r1.isChecked() || r2.isChecked()) || r3.isChecked() || r4.isChecked() || r5.isChecked())
                {
                    riskLevel = Question1Activity.countPoints;
                    if(riskLevel >= 6 && riskLevel <= 9)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Question7Activity.this, "High Risk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), HighRiskActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if(riskLevel >= 3 && riskLevel <= 5)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Question7Activity.this, "Moderate Risk" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    if(riskLevel >= 1 && riskLevel <= 2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Question7Activity.this, "Low Risk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    if(riskLevel == 0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Question7Activity.this, "No Risk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else                {
                    Toast.makeText(Question7Activity.this, "Well buddy nice try", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

Ah I fixed it I had to remove the not symbol from in front of the isChecked() conditions.